# Second drop down list based off of first drop down list using one php file

Tags: php, mysql, forms

OK I did my first successful SQL query that generated a drop down box in PHP! (yes I am still a big noob)

So my next question....

If I hit the select button, must I create a new page or can I have a 2nd drop down box be generated on the same page based upon the the submission of first list?

I saw this: [response to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6282572/2227549)

But I am still unsure of form action and method.Keep it Self? Do I need/should I use 2 separate forms? (I am not ready to tackle AJAX and far from ready to tackle Java so please keep those options off the table :) ) Or should I just pass on to a second file.

if it can be done can you explain the form  action and method used in each form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not ready for AJAX or Javascript then you'll need to add a second PHP page which will process the user's selection from the first drop-down box and display the appropriate second drop-down.

If you're new to all this then I'd advise you to keep it simple to begin with! Submitting a form and displaying a new page is the most basic way.

So in your first page's HTML you'll need...

```
<form action="second_page.php" method="post">
<select name="selection"> ... your drop-down code goes here ... </select>
<button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

Then in second_page.php you'll need...

```
$selection = $_POST['selection']; // The variable $selection holds the user's selection
```

You can then output a second page based on the value of $selection.

Comment: ok so far so good but I dont; think I am passing the correct variable: 'code' $wquery="select week_num,week_name from stats_week where season=$this_season order by week_num";
 $wresult=mysql_query($wquery);
  print "Select Week:<select name='Week_select'><br>\n";
     while ($wrow=mysql_fetch_array($wresult))
  { 
  print '<option value="'.$wrow['week_num'].'">'.'week '.$wrow['week_num'].'     '.$wrow['week_name'].'</option><br>\n'; 
  }
 print "</select>";
  print'<button type="submit" >Next</button>';
  print"</form>"; 'code'

Comment: It's the ```<select name=="Week_select">``` which you need to check for in your second script. Note that this is case-sensitive! Best do it all lower-case, then in your second script: ```$week_select = $_POST['week_select'];```

Comment: Have you put the opening part of the ```<form>``` in there too? You should have ```print '<form action="name_of_second_script.php" method="post">';``` before your ```<select>```

Comment: If you want to see what the first page is sending to the second page, put this at the start of the second page code: ```echo"<PRE>";print_r($_POST);die();``` So you can make sure it's actually sending what it should be!

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer doing it via Ajax and JQuery, something like this :

```
function getClassList(elem)
{
    var contentRequests, contentarr;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    try
    {
// Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        contentRequests = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    catch (e)
    {
// Internet Explorer Browsers
        try
        {
            contentRequests = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) 
        {
            try
            {
                contentRequests = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } 
            catch (e)
            {
// Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
        contentRequests.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(contentRequests.readyState == 4&& contentRequests.status==200)
            {


                document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = contentRequests.responseText;

            }
        }

        var urltofetch="index.php?methodname=getclasses"

        contentRequests.open("GET", urltofetch, true);
        contentRequests.send(null);


}


function getStudentList(classelem,elem)
{

   var classToFetch =  classelem + " option:selected";

   var contentRequests, contentarr;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    try
    {
// Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        contentRequests = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    catch (e)
    {
// Internet Explorer Browsers
        try
        {
            contentRequests = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) 
        {
            try
            {
                contentRequests = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } 
            catch (e)
            {
// Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
        contentRequests.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(contentRequests.readyState == 4&& contentRequests.status==200)
            {


                document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = contentRequests.responseText;

            }
        }
        var classname = $(classToFetch).text();
        alert(classname);
        var urltofetch="index.php?methodname=getstudents&cname="+classname

        contentRequests.open("GET", urltofetch, true);
        contentRequests.send(null);

}
```

Comment: that looks more like Ajax/Javascript, than Ajax/JQuery.

Comment: thanks, but since I am just starting to get my feet wet, I think I will stick with keeping it entirely in php.